# Create HBase table from CSV file format programmatically and load its content

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, bigdata

Hi I am quite new to hadoop and I am trying to import a csv table to Hbase using MapReduce.

I am using  Cloudera 5.9

i would like firsly to create an HBase table  programmatically  from a CSV table format using MapReduce(because i use a csv file composed by very large number of columns) then load the content of the CSV file to HBase table

Please can any one guide me or show me how resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

HBase tables can be created pro-grammatically. For reference using Java API's see  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_create_table.htm

Also while creating a table in HBase you don't have to create all the columns just need to create the column families (think of a column family as a group of columns and are stored together. HBase is columnar). As part of loading your content (PUT) columns can be created/used and data inserted/updated. For Java API refer
http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/

Answer (score 0):

I have used following two approaches in order to upload the data into cluster's database (HBase):

1. CSV -> HDFS
   I often have data in the CSV format. It turned out to be quite tricky to automate the process of turning a CSV file into a Hive/Impala database table. Here are the necessary steps:

a. read the csv file and make the necessary transformations. It is important to analyse the column names of the data in the csv file, however, one has to create a copy of the file which does not contain the header line.

b. then I create a folder on the cluster's name node machine (still not HDFS)

`mkdir -p input`

c. and copy my csv file(without the header line) into the folder created above using JSch java library which supports SFTP protocol:

```
public static void copyFileToLinux(String dest, String user, String password, String file) throws JSchException, SftpException,     FileNotFoundException {
 String destination = "/home/"+user+"/"+dest;
 jsch = new JSch();
 session = jsch.getSession(user,"host",22);
 session.setPassword(password);
 session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
 session.connect();
 ChannelSftp channel = null;
 channel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
 channel.connect();
 File localFile = new File(file);
 channel.cd(destination);
 channel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile),localFile.getName());
 channel.disconnect();
 session.disconnect();
}
```

Here is the dependency for JSCH:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
 <version>0.1.53</version>
</dependency>
```

d. when the csv file is on the linux master machine it can easily be put into HDFS by the following commands (I first remove a potentially present file with the same name):

```
hdfs dfs -rm input/file.csv
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p input
hdfs dfs -put input/file.csv input
```

e. as soon as the file is in HDFS I change rights to 777 (explanation under bullet point g)

```
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/vKey/input
```

f. Now everything is ready for the creating of the table, which can be done with a following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
table_name=$2
impala-shell -i host -q "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $2;"
impala-shell -i host -q "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE $2 (c1 INTEGER,c2 STRING,c3 INTEGER,c4 INTEGER,c5 STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/vKey/input';"
```

I create this CreateTable.sh script programmatically. The column names for the script are taken from step a). Remember that the uploaded data is without column names. For every column it is important to know its type, that's why I have written some code which analyses first n rows of the csv file and guesses whether there are integer, double, date or string values in the columns.
The script is then copied to the script folder which is created beforehand:

```
mkdir -p scripts
```

The script is executed:

```
sh scripts/CreateTable.sh input/file.csv schema.table
```

In order to execute this script the impala user has to have necessary rights for the csv file. That's why the step e) is important.

2. JDBC -> HDFS
   It is much easier to copy data into a HDFS table if reading the data directly from a data base. Therefore one can use the tool sqoop.

In the first step a parquet file is created:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service --username user -P --table schema.table --target-dir hdfs:////data/schema/table -m 1 --as-parquetfile
```

Afterwards the table can be created from the parquet file:

```
#!/bin/bash

parquet_path=$1
table_name=$2
schema=$3

hadoop fs -setfacl -R -m group:hive:rwx $parquet_path

par_file_list=`hadoop fs -ls $parquet_path | tail -n 1`
par_file=${par_file_list##* }
impala-shell -i host -q "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $schema.$table_name;"

prefix="hdfs://"
parquet_without_hdfs=${parquet_path#$prefix}

impala-shell -i host -q "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE $schema.$table_name LIKE PARQUET '$par_file'
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '$parquet_path';"
```

The drawback that you usually can not manipulate/transform the data in between as you can do with csv files, but you rather take the data as-is from the database. It is possible to add a where clause to the sqoop statement, but it is not possible to use a specific select statement.